# Hide Drawer Under Curved Header with Material UI and CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu that I need hidden behind an arch.

[image: Menu with error.]

I need it to fall behind the black, but over the blue, which is an arch (though you can't tell from this picture).

I am using material ui and my css for the appBar and the arch ('&:after') looks like this.

```
appBar: {
   backgroundColor: '#000',
   transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
     easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
     duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
   }),
   alignItems: 'center',
   '&:after': {
     content: '""',
     height: '50px',
     width: '110%',
     background: '#fff',
     borderTopLeftRadius: '50% 40%',
     borderTopRightRadius: '50% 40%',
     backgroundColor: '#00587E',
     boxShadow: 'inset 0 2px 2px #FFFFFF5C',
  },
},
```

and here is the menu, if it helps.

```
menu: {
   width: drawerWidth,
   flexShrink: 0,
   backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
   boxShadow: '0px 3px 6px #FFFAFA61',
},
drawerPaper: {
   top: '48px',
   width: drawerWidth,
   height: 232,
},
drawerHeader: {
   display: 'flex',
   alignItems: 'left',
   ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
},
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/header-with-menu-b6nz5?file=/src/Header/Header.tsx

Any help in hiding the menu would help.

Comment: this can be easier to debug if you reproduce the issue in http://codesandbox.io

Comment: Here is a link to codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/header-with-menu-b6nz5?file=/src/Header/Header.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `Drawer` a child of the blue container (the one with the arches - note that this means that you should remove the pseudo element on appbar and make blue container a React Element). Such that the blue container will have the property `overflow: hidden`.

See my comments on the code below for insight

```
<div className={classes.blueContainer}>
  <Drawer/>
</div>

blueContainer: {
  top: "42px",
  overflow: "hidden", // hide the overflowing drawer
  transform: "scale(1)", // the drawer is poition fixed, therefore this will be its new containing element
  width: "100%",
  height: "240px", // the height is so that the rest of the drawer would not overflow
  zIndex: 10, // the blue container needs to have higher stack context than appbar
  position: "fixed",
  borderTopLeftRadius: "48% 9%",
  borderTopRightRadius: "48% 9%",
  "&:before": {
    // reassigned the background to a pseudo element because of the blue container height
    content: '""',
    display: "block",
    boxShadow: "inset 0 2px 2px #FFFFFF5C",
    backgroundColor: "#00587E",
    borderTopLeftRadius: "50% 40%",
    borderTopRightRadius: "50% 40%",
    top: "110px",
    height: "60px"
  }
}
```

[image: Edit header with menu (forked)]

Comment: That worked perfectly. The menu looks like it sticks out a little over the blue container, but that is just some small tweaking to fix that! You're awesome!